# LLVM filecheck tool

Tags: llvm

I have built LLVM from source using the instructions given in the read-me of the official github repo. I need to find the path of the Filecheck tool that is supposed to come with llvm, but I cannot find it. LLVM installed several files in /usr/local/bin, such as e.g. llvm-config which I'm supposed to link to for a project and in the same directory in which llvm-config is located, a file for FileCheck is supposed to be, but there is none. Can someone please tell me whether FileCheck comes with the default llvm build and where I can find FileCheck?

Comment: It's in the utils/FileCheck directory of the LLVM build directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some reason it wasn't it utils, but in build/bin. Thanks for pointing me to the build directory though.

Comment: @eager2learn, arnt is referring to the location of the CMake files of the tool. Nevertheless, this question and the comments from both of you were useful for me. Thanks.